# Абсолютное позиционирование

Tags: html, css

Добрый вечер всем! Есть внутри блока `id="content"` - Блок слайд шоу а в нем навигатор

```
    <div id="wrapper"> <!-- ширина 980 margin: auto; -->
        <div id="content"> <!-- ширина 780 float:left;  200 для rightBar-->
    <!-- --------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
            <div id="slider"> <!-- Слайдшоу (Ротатор контента) ширина 740, padding:20px; -->
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="1.jpg"/>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="2.jpg"/>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="....jpg"/>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
                <div class="nav"> <!-- Навигация -->
                    <a href="#">1</a>
                    <a href="#">2</a>
                    <a href="#">...</a>
                </div>
            </div> 
  <!-- ------------End Слайдшоу (Ротатор контента)---------------------------- -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Никак не могу навигатора сделать по центру ротатора, пробую `position: absolute; left:50%;`(кстати `width` не константа, зависит от количество картинок в ротаторе), получается в центре от экрана а не ротатора, как сделать не от экрана а получилось от ширины ротатора?

Comment: `#content {position: relative;}` ?

Comment: Не - это не то, потому что есть hover: когда наводишь навигация появляется, а когда убираешь изчезает и по этому если relative сделать то весь блок будет двигаться то верх то низ. Похоже придется сделать с помощью JS

Comment: непонял как связано с hover

Comment: class="nav" отдельный отдельный блок же получается и когда наводишь на слайдшоу появится блок class="nav" и все нижние блоки двинется вниз например на 20px, так же когда будешь убирать весь нижний блок обратно вернется на место и каждый раз так

Comment: jsfiddle сделайте, я не понимаю в чем проблема

Comment: вам поможет определённо [calc](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp)